# Ways to show a div has more content

Tags: css, javascript, data-display

I'm basically a back end devlopper but I need to create a page displaying data in diiferent tables.

Some of the data rows may contain very large content but I chosed to make all rows the same height. So in that case I'm resizing the row to hide part of the content and I made them clickable to resize the div.

Now I'm looking to make it look like there is more data to display and I want to indicate it without using any button and a simple cursor change doesn't seem to be enough.

So far I tried to add a "fade" effect on these divs but it looks awful and as a UX rookie, I'd like some advice from more competent people. Here are screenshots to help you visualize.

[image: Reduced div]
[image: Expanded div]

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

I'd like a solution that doesn't need to add any JS code or HTML elements, could it be possible to simply use CSS ? i.e. Is there any visual trick to indicate that you can click on the div to get content ? (I've noticed that some websites do the fading trick, are there any others ?)

Comment: Welcome to the site! You might find [this similar question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/118617/11687) helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When content is truncated, ellipses (...) are a good way to indicate this to the user.

Something like this:

[image: ellipses example]

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this :
[image]

Divs with info & the white part would be hidden with a centered arrow and a shadow to show more data. Usually the less important data should be added there.

Answer (score 0):

I think a combination of the answers above is a good solution. You should provide some sort of affordance or indication that there is more data there, otherwise the user is forced to guess or use trial and error